# Image_tag to iframe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, iframe

I have this code inside image_tag

```
  <%= image_tag "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=450x300&sensor=false&zoom=16&markers=#{@presale.latitude}%2C#{@presale.longitude}", width: "300", height:"200" %>
```

Im used geocoder gem

How can I put it inside iframe?

Answer (score 0):

haml

```
%iframe{src: "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=450x300&sensor=false&zoom=16&markers=#{@presale.latitude}%2C#{@presale.longitude}", style: {width: "300", height:"200"} }
```

and html

```
<iframe src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=450x300&sensor=false&zoom=16&markers=#{@presale.latitude}%2C#{@presale.longitude}" style="width:300px; height: 200px;">/iframe>
```